# PHP display sibling pages as a set image

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to customise the following code so it displays all sibling pages of the current page, but instead of outputting them as the title, they are output as bulletpoints (styled bulletpoints so an image, 'images/bulletpoint.gif'). I have the following code that displays them as the names, but can't seem to customise them to display as an image. Any ideas?

Many thanks

```
<ul class="subnav_right">
<?php
global $post;
$current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );

wp_list_pages( array(
     'title_li' => '',
     'child_of' => $current_page_parent,
     'depth' => '1' )
);
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you uploading image or bulletpoints of total siblings?

Comment: Just want each sibling to be listed as the bulletpoint image, no text. So one image per sibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize using walker.I have done it using walker. check following code:

Walker Class:

```
class Custom_Walker extends Walker_Page {

    function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page = 0 ) {
        if ( $depth )
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';
            extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
            $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);
        if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
            $_current_page = get_post( $current_page );
            if ( in_array( $page->ID, $_current_page->ancestors ) )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
            if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
            elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        }
        elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        }

        $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );
        $icon_class = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'icon_class', true); //Retrieve stored icon class from post meta

        $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '">';
            $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $link_before;

                if($icon_class){ //Test if $icon_class exists
                    $output .= '<span class="' . $icon_class . '"></span>'; //If it exists output a span with the $icon_class attached to it
                }


            if($depth!=0){
                $output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', '', $page->ID );
            }else {
                 $output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID );
            }
            $output .= $link_after . '</a>';

        if ( !empty($show_date) ) {
            if ( 'modified' == $show_date )
                $time = $page->post_modified;
                else
                $time = $page->post_date;
                $output .= " " . mysql2date($date_format, $time);
        }
    }
}
```

Pass walker in argumnent like:

```
wp_list_pages( array( 'title_li' => '',
     'child_of' => $current_page_parent,
     'depth' => '1',
      'walker' => new Custom_Walker())
);
```

Comment: Thank you - that still outputs the page titles though? Rather than the bulletpoint image? Where do I add the code so it displays the image?

Comment: yes in functions.php. please accept answer if helpful

Comment: Yes, but it still outputting the same names? Where do i place the image link?

Comment: put class into page you are using wp_list_pages and check once. As it is working fine here

Comment: no it's still outputting the names not an image.

In the page i have

<ul class="subnav_right">
<?php
global $post;
$current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );

wp_list_pages( array( 'title_li' => '',
     'child_of' => $current_page_parent,
     'depth' => '1',
      'walker' => new Custom_Walker()) );
?>
</ul>

Is this correct?

Comment: that means you have not put class properly. Please exit into  function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page = 0 ) { echo "test";exit; and let me know it prints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64315/discussion-between-isabelle-and-bhumi-shah).